# Dnn module website page works in dnndev.me but does not load data in my Azure web app

Tags: entity-framework, azure, dotnetnuke-module

Coded dnn module in Visual Studio, the module is tied to an entity framework project. Runs great on dnndev.me page I have setup on my local windows server. I deployed to azure, ensured my entity frameworks dll files were uploaded. Installed my dnn module as an extension on my azure dnn web app. Added a new page, added my module to the page and it works as far as displaying all the buttons, text boxes, etc, but no data loads. I setup remote debugging on my azure web app, found a connection string issue. I corrected azure webconfig connection string issue, still no data loading. Performed remote debugging again, now it shows an Entity Framework error I do not know how to resolve:

> {"Schema specified is not valid. Errors: \r\nEFModel.GradLinxModel.ssdl(2,2) : error 0152: No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information."}    System.Exception {System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException}

Here is the connection string I'm using in the azure webconfig file:

> add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EFModel.GradLinxModel.csdl|res://*/EFModel.GradLinxModel.ssdl|res://*/EFModel.GradLinxModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="data source=tcp:mbansesql1.database.windows.net,1433;initial catalog=mbanse-mscst-dnn;User ID=myuserid;Password=mypw;App=EntityFramework"" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also see this message if you forget to include "EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll".

also

other possibility

You've added EF to a class library project, you also need to add it to the project that references it

Comment: Yes that was it. Due to using EF6, I forgot to include that dll in the files I published to azure, after I dropped the EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll onto the azure kudu site, it works, I see data!!. Thanks!